# Nokia suite for Ubuntu

Tags: phone, nokia

I searched everywhere but didn't find a good Nokia suite for Ubuntu that can read, write and send messages like the Windows version. Since I have no knowledge of coding, can anyone here make a nokia suite for Ubuntu for the community?

Comment: We are not an outsourcing site...

Comment: [Nokinux - Nokia PC Suite on Linux - Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/nokinux)

Comment: [Nokuntu - Unofficial Nokia PC Suite for Ubuntu!](http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.nl/2011/07/nokuntu-unofficial-nokia-pc-suite-for.html)

Comment: [nokia suite for Ubuntu - DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nokia+suite+for+Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Some Nokia Suite that might work for you:

- [Nokinux - Nokia PC Suite on Linux - Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/nokinux)
- [Nokuntu - Unofficial Nokia PC Suite for Ubuntu!](http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.nl/2011/07/nokuntu-unofficial-nokia-pc-suite-for.html)

---

Also it is better to search for an answer first here on AU, then to just ask it:

- [Posts containing 'nokia suite for ubuntu' - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Nokia%20suite%20for%20Ubuntu)
- [nokia suite for Ubuntu - DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nokia%20suite%20for%20Ubuntu)

Comment: Update of 2016: Nokuntu no longer works (e.g. 16.04.1/Xenial): `unable to open file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci//usr': Is a directory`